# View all timeline pressing the Home key

Tags: shortcut, timeline

When pressing <kbd>Home</kbd>, the expected behaviour everywhere in Blender is *Show all*. That applies to viewport, node tree, image editor and more.

In previous Blender versions, pressing <kbd>Home</kbd> on the timeline, this showed all the frame range, from start to end. Now with Blender 2.8x+, this shows the timeline for all set keyframes for the selected object. Which may be useful for some people, but I would like to have the old behaviour back.

Is there any other key to zoom the timeline to all the frame range, or is there any menu entry?